# What are the various factors that limits disk read and write speeds and on a network?

Tags: performance, hard-drive, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, lustre

How to choose a server which:

1. has high I/O performance of storage
2. is highly flexible in terms of
   adding more storage

So, basically these servers should act as storage servers for OST in lustre architecture.

So, in the process of knowing the above, I also want to know if the processing speed of CPU limits the read and write speeds of a disk. I guess storage controller takes care of the read and write. So, the cpu performance is not needed here? Please correct.

I am looking for HP servers.

Please suggest.

Comment: This is very much an "it depends" question. HP or a consultant versed in parallel file systems can assist you.

Comment: @ewwhite yes, I thought so. Will look into HP pages and support.

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you in the "build your own NAS" business?  HP (among others) has this stuff figured out probably at a cheaper price than a roll your own solution

Comment: @Jim B yes of course, I also just want to learn these things. ;)